# Tesseract OCR Dictionary Matching

Tags: tesseract

I have looked over Stack Overflow and other sources and can't seem to find a solution.  I am trying to create a Tesseract font (I have done this much successfully).  However, I would like it to limit or at least be highly influenced on whether the found words are close to those in the dictionary.  I have a list of freq_words that include the words I would like to correct.  My output for example has the word "tor" when in my dictionary I have the word "for".  No matter how I add the dictionary or lang.user_words file there is no change to the output.  I would like to know if I am missing something in this process.

My process is as such.

1. Create all the neccesary font/language files (i.e.inttemp,normproto,pffmtable,shapetable, etc).
2. getting a word list/create lang.freq-words using Wordlist2dawg
3. Joining these files with combine_tessdata and adding this to my tessdata directory where it is loaded into tesseract.
4. running tesseract with my new language

My problem is, no matter what I change the freq-words file to, nothing seems to change with my output.  I also tried adding "for" to lang.user-words (in tessdata) but again no change.

Language Files:

```
eng1.freq-dawg (created from freq_words text file)
eng1.inttemp
eng1.pffmtable
eng1.normproto
eng1.shapetable
eng1.unicharset
eng1.[fontname].exp0.[box][tif][tr][txt]
font_properties
eng1.traineddata (output file that is put in the tessdata path)
```

Config file:

```
load_system_dawg     T
load_freq_dawg       T
user_words_suffix    user-words
```

Terminal Command:

```
tesseract eng1.fontname.exp0.tif output -l eng1 /opt/local/share/tessdata/configs/config.txt
```

Please let me know if anyone has suggestions.

Comment: Did you put `user_words_suffix user-words` setting in a config file and specify it for Tesseract? Check [Issue 796](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=796).

Comment: @nguyenq Yup.  I have updated my question to include the config file I used

Comment: Just want to be sure, is your file named `eng1.user-words`?

Comment: @nguyenq yup! it is.  Also freq-dawg's words do not seem to correct "tor" to "for" either.  I would assume that its possible it just doesn't recognize that t is similar to f.  But at the same time, converting an entire page yields absolutely no differences with or without freq-dawgs.  I would think if the dictionary was involved there would be at least a few differences.